# Перемещение курсора на рабочем столе другого пользователя

Tags: c#, windows

У меня есть программа которая перемещает курсор по определенным ивентам, она запускается от `LOCAL_SYSTEM`. Перемещение курсора реализовано через стандартный инструмент windows.

```
[DllImport("user32.dll")]
[return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
private static extern bool SetCursorPos(int x, int y);
```

Но т. к. программа запущена в "*нулевой*" сессии, курсор у пользователя двигаться не будет. Читая [документацию](https://learn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-setcursorpos), я увидел что вроде как можно, с помощью `SetThreadDesktop`, перемещать курсор на обычном пользователе. Но из-за незнания как работает `Windows stations`, и отсутствия опыта работы с `p/invoke`, я не могу реализовать это сам.

Я хочу понять, будет ли моя задумка вообще работать, и если да, то хотя бы понять как примерно это сделать.

Comment: А зачем вообще это от имени системы запускать? Вообще достаточно обычной службы с галочкой доступа к десктопу?

Comment: Можете поподробнее объяснить, какая галочка? И будет ли приложение работать от имени администратора в этом случае.

Comment: Я про службу, а не приложение. Про привелегии, я полагаю что если пользователь имеет права админа, то и служба сможет их получить. Но для двигания мышкой права админа не нужны, насколько мне известно.

Comment: Права мне нужны для того, чтобы setcursorpos, из user32.dll, работал в taskmgr-е. Если не ошибаюсь, с 11 винды ввели ограничения на использование в системных приложениях.